# DevExpress WinForms / GridControl - Can't open Grid Designer for inherited forms

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I've been maintaining a suite of code for my employer for several years, and a new programmer started here recently that I've been training.  As described in the subject, the Run Designer feature/button (as seen in screenshot below) isn't available to him for forms that I've overridden and customized.  The Grid Designer is essential for modifying the data displayed by the grid.  We've spent many days trying to figure this out, so I'm posting it here in case anyone else encounters this issue.

We're using DevExpress 14.1.6 with Visual Studio 2019 [16.11.11]  (this pairing isn't officially supported).  Both of us are on Windows 10.

[image: Run Designer Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to "DevExpress 14.1\Components\Tools\Components" in your program files.  Open the file DXDesignKeys.exe and check both checkboxes (Enable design-time form skinning, and Enable visual inheritance for Developer Express controls used in Visual Studio) in the user interface, then click Apply and Close.

[image]